# Pandas Group by a range

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data like

```
{a : 100, b:102, c:500, d:99, e:78, d:88}
```

I want group it by a range with interval of 100.

Example:

```
{ 100: 2, 0: 3, 500:1 }
```

**that is in English**

1. 2 occourances of a number between 100..199
2. 1 occourances of a number between 500..599
3. 3 occourances of a number between 0..99

How to express this in pandas?

Answer (score 3):

Group by a range is usually `pd.cut`:

```
d = {'a' : 100, 'b':102,'c':500, 'd':99, 'e':78, 'd':88}
bins = np.arange(0,601,100)
pd.cut(pd.Series(d), bins=bins, labels=bins[:-1], right=False).value_counts(sort=False)
```

Output:

```
0      3
100    2
200    0
300    0
400    0
500    1
dtype: int64
```

### Update

Actually, `pd.cut` seems overkilled and your case is a bit easier:

```
(pd.Series(d)//100).value_counts(sort=False)
```

Output:

```
0    3
1    2
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: to put the result into a dict, put into a dataframe, call it `df`, and then `df.to_dict()`

Answer (score 2):

Solution with maximal value of `Series` used for bins anf for labels all values without last by `b[:-1]` in [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), then count values by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
d = {'a' : 100, 'b':102, 'c':500, 'd':99, 'e':78, 'f':88}

s = pd.Series(d)

max1 = int(s.max() // 100 + 1) * 100
b = np.arange(0, max1 + 100, 100)
print (b)
[  0 100 200 300 400 500 600]

d1 = s.groupby(pd.cut(s, bins=b, labels=b[:-1], right=False)).size().to_dict()
print (d1)
{0: 3, 100: 2, 200: 0, 300: 0, 400: 0, 500: 1}
```

Comment: turns out that `right=False` is correct and we both initially got the wrong labels :-).

Comment: @QuangHoang - Yes, exactly.